# Play video from Chrome in background on a always on top layer

Tags: windows, google-chrome

In the past I used to use an open source application with which I was able to let a YouTube video playing in a Chrome tab, then determine the region of the video and the application created an always on top overlay of that area.

I can't remember the name of it. Does anyone know it or any similar application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears you're looking for ["Picture-in-Picture" mode](https://www.howtogeek.com/fyi/chrome-70-has-picture-in-picture-now-here%e2%80%99s-how-it-works/) in Google Chrome, available since version 70.
There are also [multiple extensions](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/search/Picture-in-Picture) available that provide the same functionality.

Note that this is not exclusive to Chrome, other common browsers also support this.

Comment: Amazing to see this supported natively. Thanks a lot!